# OSX status menu not working in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I tried to add a simple status menu to the status bar with swift but it will not be shown.

with objective-c this worked:

---

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem * statusItem;
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status Menu"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

@end
```

---

But if i try to do basically the same thing in swift it doesn't do anything.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusMenu: NSMenu;

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        let bar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()

        let statusItem = bar.statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(NSVariableStatusItemLength))
        statusItem.title = "Status Menu"
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu
        statusItem.highlightMode = true
    }

}
```

There's no error, it just doesn't do anything. the function `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called since a println() inside it creates output.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: i have a simple question regarding the "override" keyword: Within the Book it says: „Overriding by accident can cause unexpected behavior, and any overrides without the override keyword are diagnosed as an error when your code is compiled.“ but you left it out for applicationDidFinishLaunching, although this func overrides the one in NSApplicationDelegate, right? So why does that work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that `statusItem` is going out of scope after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` finishes execution which in turn releases the object. This is not the case in your Objective-C code because the `statusItem` variable is declared at class level.

This should make your Swift code work:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusMenu: NSMenu;
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem?;

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        let bar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()

        statusItem = bar.statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(NSVariableStatusItemLength))
        statusItem!.title = "Status Menu"
        statusItem!.menu = statusMenu
        statusItem!.highlightMode = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to make sense. I will give it a try once I'm home this evening.

Comment: @hildende As a sidenode, I've uploaded a menu bar application written in Swift that you might find helpful (if only as a Swift reference) to Github: https://github.com/lemonmojo/StartupDisk

Comment: It works like a charm :) Thank you very much also for the github link. I'm pretty new to OSX-programming, got my first MacBook just 2 weeks ago so every help is welcome :)

Comment: When I try to build with Xcode6-Beta5 it says "No matching signing identity found" which I'm presuming means since you made the app, then Xcode won't let me build to prevent piracy and modifying of the source. So a build would be great

Comment: That's just code signing kicking in... To disable or set to your own signing identity, go to your project's settings, search for "code sign" and change the "Code Signing Identity" to "Don't code sign" or your own identity.